# TabItem: ClickListener does not work (Android/Java)

Tags: java, android, tabs

Well, my "ClickListeners" for certain "TabItems" which I would like to handle do not work unfortunately.

```
TabItem TabItem1;

        View.OnClickListener Klick = new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch(v.getId()) {
                case R.id.guiTabItem1:
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Lol wtf asdsadfdfs", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    break;
                case R.id.guiTabItem2:
                    // test
                    break;
            }
        }
    };
```

The app loads but pushing on a tab has no effect. I also tried assigning the click event to the tabs with "setOnClickListener". This results in a crash.

```
tabItem1.setOnClickListener(Klick);
```

And the following attempt also did not work:

```
tabItem1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Lol", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            }
        });
```

Here's the whole code snippet. Thanks in advance!

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ListView Liste;
    MediaPlayer Player;
    TabLayout guiTopNav;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

TabItem TabItem1 = findViewById(R.id.guiTabItem1);

View.OnClickListener Klick = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()) {
            case R.id.guiTabItem1:
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Lol wtf asdsadfdfs", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                break;
            case R.id.guiTabItem2:
                // it was the second button
                break;
        }
    }
};

tabAndreas.setOnClickListener(Klick);

}
```

Comment: Try to set tabItem1.setOnClickListener(this); and then implement in your class view.onclicklistner

Comment: @MuhammadImran Thank you for your quick reply! How do I implement "View.OnClickListener" in my main class (public class MainActivity extends Activity)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I worked out a solution. Apparently, the setOnClickListener() is not compatible with TabItems or TabLayouts. Instead, use the following solution to create a click function for tabs. Of course, three TabItems have to be categorized under one TabLayout in your designer.

```
    // #################################################################### GUI

    TabLayout guiTabs;
    guiTabs = findViewById(R.id.guiTopNav);
    guiTabs.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                switch(tab.getPosition()) {
                    case 0: Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Tab 1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
                    case 1: Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Tab 2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
                    case 2: Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Tab 3", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: The onTabReselected() gets the hit the second time a tab is hit. The debugger goes for all tabs, but the app only handles the right tab??

Answer (score 0):

And you already get the tabItem1 from the viewbyid?

```
/*Example you need to do it with the tabitem*/
button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.but);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I alread did this of course. Setting the Click Listener constantly crashes the app unfortunately. I have added some code above! :)

Answer (score 0):

After declaring the TabItem object you have to assign the TabItem view to it by using the findViewById method.This method will find the correct view by it's id and will return the view.

TabItem tabItem1 = findViewById(***R.id.tabitemview***);

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I alread did this of course. Setting the Click Listener constantly crashes the app unfortunately. I have added some code above! :)

Comment: Try to analyze the error by checking logcat view.There should be some information there about this problem.